# assign zero in unsigned short int in c

Tags: c, printf, unsigned, short, format-specifiers

I try to assign zero to a field in a structure called list

```
list.ultimo = 0;
```

but when I use printf

```
printf("%d", list.ultimo);
```

I get the result

```
32766
```

but when I add

```
unsigned short int cero = 0;
```

the result of printf is correct, no matter that does not use cero. why?

lista.h

```
#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H

typedef struct{
  elemento lista[TAMANOMAX];
  unsigned short int ultimo;
}LISTA;

void Insertar(elemento, unsigned short int posicion, LISTA);
#endif
```

lista.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef short int elemento;
#ifndef TAMANOMAX
#define TAMANOMAX 10
#endif
#include"lista.h"

void Insertar(elemento x, unsigned short int p, LISTA lista){
  if (lista.ultimo >= TAMANOMAX){
    puts("full list");
    printf("%hu",lista.ultimo); 
  }
}
```

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short int elemento;
#define TAMANOMAX 4
#include"lista.h"

int main(){
  LISTA esferas;
  esferas.ultimo = 0; 
  Insertar(2,0,esferas);
  printf("\n%hu\n", esferas.ultimo);
  return 0; 
}
```

the result is

```
$gcc -Wall lista.c main.c

full list

32765

0
```

I'm new to this, I'm slow for now, I regret the delay

Comment: Don't you think that this information is not enough? Show the definition of the structure and also the definition of `list`.

Comment: Please don't tell me `ultimo` is unsigned and you're using `%d` to print that...

Comment: @SouravGhosh hah!  You guessed wrong - it was an unsigned short

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, my bad.. I missed the title.... ;)

Comment: You should show us a little more code to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%hd` to print a `short int` and `%hu` to print an `unsigned short int`. `%d` is for `int`.

EDIT: Now that you have posted the full code, it appears that `TAMANOMAX` is set to `10` in `lista.c`, but set to `4` in `main.c`, leading to an incompatibilty between your `main()` function and the `Insertar` one. You should have the same value in all files. And if you want to work with different array lengths, add a `length` member in your `LISTA` structure. But `TAMANOMAX` should absolutely be the same everywhere, else you're in fact working with different data types and your program won't work.

Comment: while this is good advice, I don't think it answers the question. `%d` works just fine for `unsigned short` when `sizeof(unsigned short) < sizeof(int)`, and in the other case, the vale `0` should not turn into `32766` - undefined behavior or not. Something else is going on (and most likely there's missing information in the question).

Comment: thanks for responding, I think is not a problem of format specifiers with "% hu" I have the same wrong result.

Comment: Indeed, as already noticed by @SanderDeDycker. But in this case, please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, because the result you get is more than curious: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think it is a problem related to the preprocessor, with constant TAMANOMAX

Comment: thank you very much, I try to control the size of array from main.c, emulating function overloading, with the option TAMANOMAX 10 by default.

in the future will be more careful to ask and also with the code

Answer (score 1):

Using mismatched format specifier with the type of the argument invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` function

> [..] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

and about `%d` format specifier,

> `d,i`
>  The `int` argument [....]

so, `%d` expects an `int`.

As per your question title, `ultimo` is `unsigned short int` and you're using `%d` to print the value.

You should use `%hu` to print `unsigned short int`.